# Python 3 http server to host multiple windows drives on same port

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver

I know you can create servers in Python 3 through

```
def run(server_class=ThreadingHTTPServer, handler_class=CustomHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

And you can even specify custom location in `CustomHandler` constructor to hold file despite whereever the script is ran from like

```
class CustomHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, dir='D://'):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=dir)
```

**Question:**

I was wondering if there is a way to host all drives in the PC on same server's port.

I know one should use nginx or apache for such things but I am looking for pure python only solution, because I am rewriting most of `http.server` methods to build a server with some specific behaviour as per my needs.

Any clues would be appreciated.